# Cakephp 3.0 unit testing - BadMethodCallException: Unknown method

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I have a model function which I'm trying to test using phpunit. This calls a function in another, unrelated model. The second model's function is called as follows:

```
$configItems = TableRegistry::get('ConfigurationItems');
$restartDeclinedDays = $configItems->findConfigItemValue('restart_declined_days');
```

When I run the unit test, I get the following error: 
**BadMethodCallException: Unknown method "findConfigItemValue"**

How can I write the test so that this will work as expected? The code works within the application, but I'd like to have the test to cover it.

Comment: The first thing to do when stumbling over such problems, is to check whether the instance is really of the type that you are expecting: `debug(get_class($configItems));`, I guess it's `\Cake\ORM\Table`, and not your concrete table class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've had a look. I am getting the right class on it:  `ConfigManager\Model\Table\ConfigurationItemsTable`

Comment: Well, then the method doesn't seem to exist. So you app namespace is `ContactManager`? Or is that a plugin? If it's a plugin, why aren't you using the plugin syntax `ContactManager.ConfigurationItems`? Also does it show the same classname when running the app? And is the method really defined on that specific class, and not on a class that is being extended?